# I'm using flutter scaffold appbar basic project on android studio hedgehog, after running the app, the screen shows a white screen rather than blue

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I'm using flutter scaffold appBar basic project on android studio hedgehog, after running the app the output screen shows a white/blank output rather than blue appBar.

Here is the code:
Main dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp( home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar()),));
}
```

widget_test.dart:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
```

-I have tried changing "const MyApp" to "AppBar" and "MaterialApp" in test(widget) folder but still the output screen remains blank/white

`await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());`

`await tester.pumpWidget(AppBar());`

`await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp());`

following are the images of my code:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXjKr.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zZcI.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LQvW.png)

[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5zVC.png)

Comment: The app bar is there, but currently it's empty. The default blue app bar is from Material 2. In Material 3, the app bar "blends" with the body if it's not elevated

Answer (score 0):

just set a title to the AppBar,it will show up

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp( home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(" S H O W IN G"),)),));
}
```

Comment: After setting a title , the title was displaying but app bar remains white, so i changed the color to blue and booom . have i done correct?

Comment: @Xeyad the default blue app bar that you're familiar with is from Material 2. Starting from Flutter 3.16, the app will by default uses Material 3.

Comment: yes you did.

read a little bit about  those topics: Flutter themes and Material Ui  ,so this will not happen again

reference: https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/material_3_demo/

Comment: @IldebertoVasconcelos Thankyou for your support and assist. I will definitely check these documents